# Magento very slow ONLY on index.php the rest in flying

Tags: magento, nginx, php

I have a Magento 1.13 EE with multiple website installation on my dedicated server.

Loading homepage takes 4 to 5 seconds, but when I'm in it's just run smooth.

Tests I've run so far:

1. `ping www.mykidz.it` (even ping is taking 5seconds!!)

   ```
   PING mykidz.it (37.247.48.38) 56(84) bytes of data.
   64 bytes from 37.247.48.38: icmp_req=1 ttl=56 time=6.79 ms
   ```
2. curl + time

   ```
   $ curl -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total}\\n http://www.mykidz.it
   3,809 second
   ```
3. curl + time for another file for testing purpose (jpg is 1MB size) -->

   ```
   $ curl -o /dev/null -s -w %{time_total}\\n http://www.mykidz.it/cat.jpg
   0,027 seconds
   ```

I already restarted my webserver (nginx) and php (php5-fpm) but the problem is still there..

Does anyone have an idea on how to fix this issue?

Comment: Most probably it has something to do with the content of your homepage. I see that you have some categories thumbnails. How do you retrieve these categories? Can you provide some code for that block? You can try to change the content of the homepage with a simple text and see if it still takes that long to load.

Comment: YOu might have more luck asking over at ServerFault — the ping has nothing to do with the web server/Magento, so your issues seems more like some sort of network latency.

Comment: Strip things away one by one on the homepage until the page performs good again.  Eventually you'll pinpoint where the heavy loading is occurring.

Comment: @AlanStorm ping aside, if there were any network latency, whay fetching index.php is taking 3.8seconds (4k size) but fetching cat.jpg  take only 0.027 (1mb size)?

Comment: @Axel what if i tell you that this problem was born only 4/5 days ago and before this, site was working just fine?

Comment: @Marius good idea, will try this..merci Marius

Comment: @user2960785 - If that's the case, and no code changes were made within the last 4-5 days, then my guess would be a bottleneck somewhere in your server (database/filesystem).

Comment: @Axel and this bottleneck can have influence only on index.php and not on other files? for me it's just very very strange..i'll try following first what Marius told me..then look after a possible bottleneck..thanks!

Comment: @user2960785 Who knows — when network latency's at play all rules are off.  You're better off solving that ping problem first.

Comment: ok looks like client did not cached some block in homepage. now index.html loads much faster...thx to all